# Redirect unauthorized users to a custom page error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to redirect unauthorized users to a custom page when they are accessing administrator pages but I'm getting errors..

Web.Config For Administrator Folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrators" />
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Login page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
                    Response.Redirect("~/ErrorUNTH.aspx");
            }
}
```

ERRORS After loggin as NORMAL USER and accessing Administrator page:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are getting generic error message. Turn of custom errors  <customErrors mode="Off"/> and attach the correct error message to your post.

Comment: Well we cannot guess the error, you need to disable custom errors. Add this configuration `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />` under `<system.web>` and let us know the specific error. It would also be a good idea that you allow debug `<compilation debug="false">`

Comment: I did that and I get the same error

Comment: * means all users right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719554(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  `<deny users="*"/>` and add `<deny users="?"/>`

1. `?` - Anonymous user
2. `*` - all users

And also *remove* the code from `Page_Load` event.

If user is not logged then will redirected automatically to *login.aspx*. Take a look at `<authentication>` section of root `web.config`.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl ="mylogin.aspx"/> <!-- You can change the url -->
</authentication>
```

Comment: Yes but I want to redirect unauthorized to a certain page not to the login page

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the content of "401 Access Denied" response (if this is the case) by adding the following code in the Application_EndRequest event of Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, 
                                             EventArgs e)
  { 
     HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
     if (context.Response.Status.Substring(0,3).Equals("401"))
     {
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.Write("<script language="javascript">" + 
                     "self.location='../login.aspx';</script>");
     } 
  }
```

When browser recognizes 401 and there are no credentials the client side redirection will take place. The browser will show a custom 401 page.